# BxSlider stopping on pagination click

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#slider1').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    pager: true
  });
```

I have this code, and if I click on page navigation bottons, the slider stop auto. I tried several solutions, but with no success!

P.S.: bxSlider V3!

Comment: If you're still looking for an answer, the maker of bxslider says that this is intended functionality. Not really sure how to change that.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable code line in bxslider.js:

```
if (slider.settings.auto) el.stopAuto(); //custom by ken
```